# Como mostrar janela "Salvar como" no momento do download?

Tags: php

Como baixo o vídeo que tem a opção de "salvar como", em php, já tentei. parece que está faltando alguma coisa, sempre baixar

index.php:

```
<form action="down.php" method="post" name="url">
<input name="url" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

down.php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['url'])){
  $fileName = $_POST['url'];
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"video.mp4\"");
    readfile('video.mp4');
    exit;
}else{
    echo 'O video não existe.';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Não tem como**, a caixa de dialogo <kbd>Salvar como</kbd> é uma opção do navegador de escolha do usuário, não tem como forçar ela aparecer via scripts, nem scripts *server-side* e nem scripts *client-side* (como JavaScript).

Existem navegadores que baixam diretamente, por exemplo os mobiles existem navegadores que mostram a tal caixa de dialogo para salvar por padrão, mas a única coisa que você pode fazer é disponibilizar um link com uma informação dizendo:

> Clique com o botão direito e selecione *"Salvar como..."*

Só assim desta maneira a caixa de dialogo aparece sem precisar configurar o navegador

O usuário de um navegador Desktop é quem decide se quer que baixa diretamente (geralmente para pasta `Downloads`) ou se lhe é exibido o dialogo perguntando aonde deseja salvar, por exemplo, no Chrome se você navegar digitando na barra de endereço `chrome://settings/?search=downloads`, notará isto:

[image: configurar chrome]

Veja que a opção esta desabilitada, se você habilitar esta opção todo e qualquer download irá terá a caixa de dialogo perguntando se deseja *Abrir* ou *Salvar/Guardar* o download e nem precisará clicar com o direito do mouse/rato, acaso esteja desabilitado vai salvar diretamente na pasta *Downloads* padrão do seu sistema (geralmente, mas é possível alterar a localização da pasta).